# Render MVC View Section From Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Here is my ***MVC View*** section:

```
@section popups{
    <div class="popup-class" id="popup">
        <div class='btn-group' id='actions'>
            <div class='collapse navbar-collapse'>
                <ul class='actions'>
                    <li class='dropdown'>
                        <a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle grid-icon' data-toggle='dropdown'></a>
                        <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                            <li><a href='#'>Product</a></li>
                            <li><a href='#'>Test</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='clear'>
        </div>
            </div>
}
```

I want to call it from JavaScript file (only this section).How can i do that?

Comment: You have already added ID to div. Simply use that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get a asp.net mvc `section` in javascript. What you can do is define an html element around the section on the layout page, a `<div>` for sample, and get this element, for sample, in your layout page:

```
<div id="popups">
@RenderSection("popups", false)
</div>
```

In your javascript code, just call this element, for sample:

```
$(function(){
   // call the element, call a method
   $("#popups").show();
});
```

You do not specify what you want to do with this.